# Call a stored procedure from a select statement in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server 2016 database with a table that stores an XML file. What I want to do if possible is to call another stored procedure and pass in the `ApplicationID` value.

My code is

```
select 
    RecID, 
    nref.value('APPLICATION_ID[1]','varchar(max)') ApplicationID ,
    nref.value('FY[1]','varchar(max)') FY 
into
    ADMIN_stagingTable
from 
    [ADMIN_Grant_Exporter_Files_XML] 
cross apply 
    XMLData.nodes('PROJECTS[1]/row[1]') as R(nref)
where 
    nref.value('ORG_DUNS[1]', 'varchar(max)') = '183710748'
```

I'm currently storing it into a staging table. Is there a better way than looping the result set?

```
SELECT @APPLICATION_ID = ApplicationID 
FROM ADMIN_stagingTable

EXECUTE  [Parse_Exporter] @APPLICATION_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using function.
you can put the script of the SP in a function and then you can call it
name the function fn_Parse_Exporter

and use like this

```
SELECT *, dbo.fn_Parse_Exporter(ApplicationID)
FROM My_Table
```

Comment: That could work - I'll give that a try.  The Stored Procedure is a bitch of a XML parseing routine.  But this is interesting.  Thanks

Comment: @user1314159 FYI: there are also ways to run SP from the function if you don't want to duplicate the code

Comment: doesn't look that will work for me because I am deleteing and inserting data into tables and I get an error of Invalid use side-effecting operator Insert within a function

Comment: I've marked this as the answer but I can't use it now but can use it in another place